# Qwidget window disappears

Tags: pyqt4

Okay... This has been bugging me for hours. I have a qtmainwindow with a menubar.  I've managed to  connect an action in tje menubar to an independent Qwidget. But as soon as the Qwidget appears it disappears. I'm using the latest version of pyqt.

Here's the code:

```
Import sys
from PyQt4  import QtGui,  QtCore

Class Main(QtGui.QtMainWindow) :
         def __init__(self) :
               QtGui.QtMainWindow.__init__(self) 
               self.setGeometry(300,300,240,320) 
               self.show() 

               menubar  = self. menuBar() 

               filemenu = menubar. addMenu('&File') 

               new = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('new.png'), 'New', self) 
               new.triggered.connect(self.pop) 
               filemenu.addAction(new) 

      def pop(self) :
            pop = Pop() 

class Pop(QtGui.QWidget) :
         def __init__(self) :
               QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self) 
              self.setGeometry(300,300,240,320>
              self.setWindowTitle('Pop up') 
             self.show()
```

Comment: Questions about implementation and debugging existing code likely belong on Stack Overflow.  Please read the [help/on-topic] to get a better idea of questions that are appropriate for Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update the `pop(self)` method as:

```
def pop(self):
    self.window = Pop()
```

you need to store object of newly created window in a member variable, other wise as soon as the method finishes with the execution, local variables will be destroyed by the Python *Garbage Collector*.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!!  I also found out that I could use  Qdialog  and use exec_()  instead but with a local variable.

Comment: QDialog has a specific purpose, call to `exce_()` method blocks the execution of the code at this point until the user closes the dialog. That's why `QDialog` does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

if you implement this code, you will see the window gets created and disappears immediately.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
window.setWindowTitle("GUI window")
window.show()
```

To solve that problem write "sys.exit(app.exec_())" after window.show() and the window will stay on the screen.